# Is there an example of fields $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$ where $L/K$ and $K/F$ are normal but $L/F$ is not normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm searching(I searched this site first) for example of fields $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$ where $L/K$ and $K/F$ are normal but $L/F$ is not normal. Presenting some fields just for $F$ or $L$, instead of all three fields will help me too. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I read it but I don't know the relation between normal and Galois extention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider $$\Bbb{Q} \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$$

Comment: I had mistake in meaning of normal extension. ... if K is a splitting field of "a set" of polynomials over F. I don't attend to "a set" and read "set of all".

Comment: $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q [\sqrt{2}] \subseteq \Bbb Q [\sqrt[4]{2}]$

Comment: @HoseynHeydari Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Even before going for normal extensions, It would be useful to see if you can find a chain of subgroups $G_1\subset G_2 \subset G_3$ such that :

$G_3$ is normal over $G_2$ and $G_2$ is normal over $G_1$ but $G_3$ is not normal over $G_1$.

make sure your $G_3$ is galois group of some known polynomial..

Then, by Fund. Theorem of Galois groups you can find :

corresponding extensions for $G_1,G_2,G_3$ as $F_1,F_2,F_3$  respectively such that

$F_3$ is normal over $F_2$ (Galois) and $F_2$ is Normal over $F_1$ (Galois)

But, $F_3$ is not normal over $F_1$ (Not Galois).

For same problem you can see this link :

[Dummit and Foote, Exercise 14.2.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455600/dummit-and-foote-exercise-14-2-9)